# Is there a way to override the load method of a bundle in SF4?

Tags: php, overriding, bundle, symfony4

I am trying to use `Webonaute/DoctrineFixturesGeneratorBundle` (a bundle for generating fixtures from database data via a symfony console command) on a Symfony 4.2 project. It is officially supported according to the `README.md`, but it doesn't work.

```
Command "doctrine:generate:fixture" is not defined.
```

After a search on Google, I discovered that I am not alone in having a problem with this bundle on SF 4.2 and I found a PR (opened for months) that solves the problem.

https://github.com/Webonaute/DoctrineFixturesGeneratorBundle/pull/57/files

I applied the patch directly into the vendor directory and it works. But, I would like to override the class without modify the vendor.

So, is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Fork it, apply patch, add your fork to composer repositories => profit. Or have a look at the one, who submitted pull request, probably he has fixed fork in his repos

Comment: Yes! I didn't think about the fork. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add the repo in the composer.json file.

```
"repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/PapyDanone/DoctrineFixturesGeneratorBundle.git"
        }
    ],
```

Do not forget to authorize bundles in dev state.

```
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
```

However, I had to fix other things on the project, to make the bundle compatible with Symfony 4. Then, I forked the repo of the person who submitted the pull request, corrected it and made a new pull request to the original repo.